# Data-mapper and Cassandra

Tags: ruby, nosql, cassandra, datamapper

I not sure I have understood all the principles of nosql, especially Cassandra project, but I like to know if it's possible to have Cassandra working with Data-mapper ?
I working on a ruby application using Data-mapper and MySQL and start to think of migrating to Cassandra. Is that something easy and worth doing ?
Thanks a lot,
Luc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Migrating from MySQL to Cassandra is usually not something people describe as "easy" for nontrivial applications, but http://github.com/NZKoz/cassandra_object/tree/master can help.